# How to perform 03 optimisation correctness check (testing)

Tags: gcc, optimization, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

How to test that on -O3 Optimisations are performed correctly? I have a listed few of -O3 Optimisations(LLVM)and these are target independent.

One way is we can find some standard test suites which has test cases for validating these optimisations(since these are target independent).But, I do not know which are those standard test suites.

```
----- CallGraph Construction
----- Strip Unused Function Prototypes
----- Loop Load Elimination
----- A No-Op Barrier Pass
----- Simplify the CFG
----- Eliminate Available Externally Globals
----- Alignment from assumptions    
----- Merge Duplicate Global Constants
----- Jump Threading
----- Dead Store Elimination
----- Scalar Evolution Analysis
```

Could you please help me, is there anyway of verifying these optimisations?
Does LLVM (or dejagnu) have test suite which covers testcases for all target independent optimisations?

Comment: Both GCC and LLVM have testsuites. They're both documented and easy to find with google.

Comment: @asm, thanks for the suggestion. Yes i had looked into it but couldn't find test cases for particular optimisations in both GCC and LLVM. I see basic optimisation list in Nullstone tes-tsuite which are very small in number.

Comment: I can't speak to LLVM test suites, but GCC's are indeed mostly whole-compiler tests. They have a test case and compile it at 6 different optimization levels to check they all run.  Then there are regression tests that check particular bugs have not recurred.

Comment: Okay, but I could not find any test related to above mentioned list of optimisations. For instance I have searched for `CallGraph Construction` in GCC test-suite but could not find any test case related to it. Could you please guide me by locating the test case path that you are referring? Thank You.